js/jquery problems doing pre-submit $(document).on("submit",'#edditSight', function() looping before submission
the goal at the moment is to just stop the submission however the Jquery seems to loop a number of times before it stops.
tryed
var run = 0
function loadJobSights(loadedJobSight){

    var jobSight = loadedJobSight.split(",");
    L.marker([parseFloat(jobSight[0]),parseFloat(jobSight[1])])
    .bindPopup('<B>NOT WORKING DO NOT SUBMIT</B><form id="edditSight" action="saveData.php" method="POST"><input type="submit"></form>')
    .addTo(map);
    $(document).on("submit",'#edditSight', function() {
        try{
            run++
            console.log('working', run);
            return false;
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            return false;
        }
                  
    });
}

this output
working 1
working 2
working 3

I need it to only output once

Do you get some errors?

Doesn't seem to be related to PHP. Would you be able to create a minimal, reproducible example so we could offer better suggestions? Your other function is using latlng_utm. Can you please show us how that function is defined, and what the jobSight looks like after splitting?

"sure it's a syntax error" - for js, check the browser console - it's not shy in telling you where you've gone wrong (if at all)

Change $('#edditSight').submit(function() {... to $(document).on("submit", "#edditSight", function() {...

Always check your selectors - liberally add lines line console.log($('#edditSight').length) eg just before $('#edditSight').submit - if it's not 1 then the issue is that the element doesn't exist yet - so you need event delegation (as in my comment above).  jQuery silently ignores when your selector doesn't find any elements (which is actually a good thing)

bindPopup() doesn't add the form until you click on the item. But you're trying to add the submit handler immediately, before the form has been added to the DOM.

@fdomn-m your solution does stop the submission but then it loops and calls the function continuously

@Barmar where should I put the handler? I did try to put it in the HTML int  bindPopup() but it didn't work

"trying to add the submit handler immediately, before the form has been added to the DOM" - you should use event delegation.    If it's "calling the function continuously" then it's likely you've implemented it incorrectly (what's "the function"?).  Can you update with what you've tried?

@PhilosophiCat You should do what fdomn-m said above. That's called event delegation, and it's the way to bind handlers to dynamically-created elements.

@fdomn-m  so i tried 'console.log($('#edditSight').length);' and it changes numbers when form"addNewSight" is visible and not when form edditSight is visible. I did not run console.log($('#addNewSight').length);'

Ok, the console.log is just to show you that the form is added/removed as Barmar has explained "bindPopup() adds the form when you click on the item".    This shows that $("#id").submit( won't work - so you need to use $(document).on("submit", "#id", function...

@fdomn-m "Ok, the console.log is just to sho..." ok thanks
